# iPad Gallery Reveal Feature

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I've been searching for a library or open source project that does something like the iPad gallery reveal feature, spread to reveal photos in an album, pinch to close. Does anyone know of such a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having trouble finding this is that applications have been rejected for implementing this feature.  Read [this](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/04/07/apple_rejected_ipad_app_for_using_pinch_to_expand_gesture.html) for more details.